# Pass Value from input text area on button click to database

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, oledb, ole

How do I pass value that is entered into a text input field to following

```
objCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", value)
```

Comment: MVC doesn't seem relevant here.  Did you mean ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want this

```
objCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", txtInput.Text).
```